# Set up 2 webapp in same war file

Tags: war, websphere-liberty

Our Angular project is currently deloyed with a war to websphere server. The Angular project is built into css, htmls and index.html. These files are put under the webapp folder and maven build/package the war.

Now we want to deploy 2 Angular project: A and B. so if you visit {root}/A then index.htl of A project is returned and if you visit {root}/B, index.html of B project will be returned.

Current project is simple

[image]

decompressed war file is like this

[image]

What I think is, if I can create 2 folders under webapp, A and B. move the folders `assets`, `config`, `WEB_INF`, and all the js and other files into A. Similarily move all B related to folder B. Can this way build a war file servers A at /A and B at /B?

Thanks

Comment: This should be possible as long as `root-context` of your app will be `/`